# log4j2 RollingFile on Windows gives "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: java, windows, log4j2

I'm trying to configure log4j2 with a `RollingFile` appender, in order to have previous log files saved and a fresh logfile per run.

The appender in log4j2.xml is configured as follows:

```
    <RollingFile name="Logfile" >
        <append value="false" />
        <filePattern value="log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm}.txt" />
        <fileName value="log.txt" />
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%N] [%-5level] [%-16t] [%-20logger{36}]: %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

When I run the application, I immediately get the following error:

```
2016-07-26 12:15:54,888 main ERROR Unable to create file  java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    ...
2016-07-26 12:15:54,919 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
```

Using a simple `File` appender creates the desired log file within my program directory, so I expected that the `RollingFile` appender would also be able to handle relative paths. It may does, because absolute paths don't work either. If I prepend the path of my programs directory or the actual value of my `%TMP%` env var to `fileName` and `filePattern`, I get the same error.

So any help on configuring log4j2 for my goals is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileName` and `filePattern` are attributes to the RollingFile tag, not child tags:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
             filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
```

See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender